# PUT method using python3 and urbllib - headers

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, put

So I am trying to just receive the data from this json. I to use POST, GET on any link but the link I am currently trying to read. It needs [PUT]. So I wanted to know if I was calling this url correctly via urllib or am I missing something?

```
Request
{"DataType":"Word","Params":["1234"], "ID":"22"}

Response {
 JSON DATA IN HERE
}
```

I feel like I am doing the PUT method call wrong since it is wrapped around Request{}.

```
import urllib.request, json
from pprint import pprint
header = {"DataType":"Word","Params":"[1234"]", "ID":"22"}
req = urllib.request.Request(url = "website/api/json.service", headers = 
heaer, method = 'PUT')
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read(), decode())
    pprint(data)
```

I am able to print json data as long as its anything but PUT. As soon as I get a site with put on it with the following JSON template I get an Internal Error 500. So I assumed it was was my header.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Could you please check you code, it does not highlight properly thus there is most likely an error around `"[1234"]"` with the quote chars, that would help much in helping you. Further you use `headers = 
heaer` which will most likely not work, again not sure if this is a typo when removing the actual URL form your code for pasting.

Comment: I recommend using `requests` btw. if you are able to install it in your environment. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/